Mapping result of aggregate function with class in OOP
I have a scenario where I'm designing a class Student.
public class Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string section;
    int semester;
}

I have a scenario that I want to display the count of each student in a semester.
For example semester 1 has 20 students. Semester 2 has 40 students.
In the database, I can get it using count(*).
But how would I map it with Class? Because class doesn't have a totalStudentInSemester attribute, neither it makes sense to have it
I am not getting how to map the count result with the class... Or how to return the value from database with details. I am using ADO.NET and later may use EF Core
The query can be:
SELECT semester, COUNT(*) AS student_count
FROM Students
GROUP BY semester;


The Student class itself doesn't have this knowledge, nor should it. You'd need a collection of some kind to hold the students, such as a List<Student> or an array (Student[]) (depending on your use case). Then, depending on the collection type, you could call something like .Count(s => s.Semester == 1). I suggest reading up on collections in .NET, probably starting with basic arrays and List<T>.

Yes, the student data will be stored in List.
Actually I want to retrieve the data from database by a query, Let me edit the question

If you want an object-oriented answer (as indicated by the oop tag), you could define a Semester class that holds all the students in the semester. Idiomatically in OOP you'd derive it from a base class, such as Collection<T>:
public sealed class Semester : Collection<Student>
{
}

Since the base class already defines a Count property, you can just query that value after having added the Student objects to a Semester object.
But as others have pointed out, you may not need to make it that complicated. If you put the Student objects in an array, you can just query the array's Length.

SELECT semester, COUNT(*) AS student_count
FROM Students
GROUP BY semester;
Actually I have to display this result.
One way as answered by @Tobias Bulk
foreach(var semester in students.GroupBy(student => student.semester))
{
Console.WriteLine($"Semester {semester.Key}: {semester.Count()} students");
}
But for this we have to load whole student data in ram.
I want to do without loading whole data...
and performining Count() in database

It is difficult to give a complete answer, since we do not know how you are accessing the database. But in any case, you have several options to map the result.

Use a dedicated class:
public class SemesterCount
{
    public int Semester { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}


Use an Anonymous type. This is only useful if you are using the result locally:
new { Semester = <get semester>, Count = <get count> }


Use a ValueTuple:
(Semester: <get semester>, Count: <get count>)



Assuming that you are using an object relational mapper like EF Core, you could do something like this:
// Example using EF Core and ValueTuples
using var context = new SchoolContext();
var result = context.Students
    .GroupBy(s => s.semester)
    .Select(g => (Semester: g.Key, Count: g.Count());

This creates a SQL SELECT command with a GROUP BY clause that is executed by the db engine. But even if you are using ADO manually, you can map the result manually to one of these three kinds of objects.

Thank you for all the different ways!
The class name would be better SemesterCount or Semester?
The only purpose of class Semester is to able to map the counts.. right?
In a similar situation, we can have like a product class having attributes ID ModelName, Price.... We can return the quantity by count group by ModelName...
For that we would make ProductQuantity class?

Semester would be a good name for the semesters themselves (who could be stored in a table). E.g. a Semester class could contain semester number, year or a plain text like "First semester", start date etc., i.e., data directly related to the semester, whereas SemesterCount or SemesterStatistics would really only contain the result of an evaluation.

using the counting method you can group each semester's counting on a map
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = studentList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getSemester, counting()));
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach(integerIntSummaryStatisticsEntry -> {
        System.out.println(integerIntSummaryStatisticsEntry.getKey() +":"+integerIntSummaryStatisticsEntry.getValue());
    });
}

